# table cell views are not right aligned

Tags: ios, uitableview, right-to-left

I am trying to right-align my table cells.

[image: simulator]

I have set 'Semantic' property to 'Force Right-to-Left' value through the whole visual tree.

Desired layout:

[image: Desired state]

Visual tree:

[image: Visual tree]

There aren't any visual definitions in code...

**EDIT:**

After @dirtydanee suggestion:

[image: trailed]

Comment: Your cells are right aligned, just as you specified. You would like to align your text to the right and starting from longest one?

Comment: Forgot to expand the constraints in screenshot. I want to pin the text to the right corner. Hebrew is read from right to left. Will try to draw the desired layout soon.

Comment: Try this tutorial will solve your problems: https://medium.com/if-let-swift-programming/working-with-localization-in-swift-4a87f0d393a4

I am using it also for Arabic version of my app. 

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[image: Stack view configuration]

For your stack view you should have `alignment` set to `Leading` to make it start at the leading position for your language, which is the right most side for you. Then you set `Semantic` to `Force Right-to-Left`.

It is important that you have tied the stack views edges to it's container's edges, so that the stack view will size to it's container. It is also important that you let the labels have dynamic size. Both of these conditions seems to be met in your code, although it is not entirely clear.

Answer (score 1):

Just do following thing to assign text right side in **tableviewCell**

- Step 1: Select view in contect View cell in StoryBoard
- Step 2: Alignment text to right side.

[image: Description image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your constraints are wrong.

Constrain your labels to the right and align their text to the right.

Here is an example:

[image]

And running on simulator:

[image]

Comment: That doesn't work :-(. [about the other question - It didn't work. if i would accept your answer it will reduce my chances to receive an alternate answer from other users. Nevertheless i gave you the whole bounty.]

Comment: Thanks, I really want to help you, Which version of Xcode are you using? Which language Swift/obj-c?

Comment: Also, did you copied my constraints? BTW I didn't edit any localizations settings and I've tested this example on device with English set as language

Comment: Xcode 8.3.2. Swift 3. I did copy them. I also think it has nothing to do with localizations.

Comment: Can you please add a photo of your attribute inspector? its the one with  the small shield sign

Answer (score 1):

If you use `leading` and `trailing` constraints to layout your `UILabel` elements, everything gets switched automagically to the right site if using a Right-To-Left language. There is **no** need to change the `NSTextAlignment` (`.natural` is default and the one you need) or the `UISemanticContentAttribute` of the `UILabel`. [image]

---

**Be aware that you need to have at least one RTL language added to your project localizations:**

[image]

---

When the language of your iPhone / iPad is set to Hebrew everything should work as expected:

[image]

Comment: I didn't edit any localizations settings and I've tested this example on device with English set as language

Comment: @inspector_60 I don't get your point. What are you trying to tell us?

Comment: The solution should not be limited to "Hebrew" only devices.
The reason it doesn't worked for @Dorad must be other

Comment: @inspector_60 This is how you build your interface for ltr *and* rtl languages. If this solution is useful or not is up to Dorad.

Answer (score 0):

It is also depend on Your Device Selected Lang.

You can try to use `left`  instead of `leading` and use `right` instead of `trailing`

Comment: is it working for you ? or not ?, also  You can set text alignment natural

Comment: Does not work. neither setting text alignment natural

Comment: Anywhere you are putting attributed text ? and also your constraints should be  like this  ,  Right : ( Your const  = )  , top :  (Your COnst = ), Bottom : (Your Cons =) and **Left**  : (Greater than (Your Const))

Comment: No attributed text. will try your suggested constrains later and will let you know.

Comment: Ok  Good Luck,   By seeing your output you have correctly done all things except constraints ,

Answer (score 0):

I tried a demo and i think what you need to do is set semantic for each label separately

go to perekSourcelabel set semantic right-to-left 
then do same for header label

dont set semantic for your stack view or the whole perekTableViewcell

Answer (score 0):

Duplicating another well-aligned scene (View Controller) and deleting the corrupted one solved it.

Not sure what the problem was.